# I18n routes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-i18n

I want to program in english but my output routes must be in another language.

Today I'm using the following approach and I'm not getting the `index` action and `new` and `edit` still missing translation. I've tried to use `test: one: other:` without success.

```
resource :activities, path: I18n.t('routes.test')

# config/routes.rb

     activities POST   /teste(.:format)            activities#create
 new_activities GET    /teste/new(.:format)        activities#new
edit_activities GET    /teste/edit(.:format)       activities#edit
                GET    /teste(.:format)            activities#show
                PATCH  /teste(.:format)            activities#update
                PUT    /teste(.:format)            activities#update
                DELETE /teste(.:format)            activities#destroy

# config/locales/routes.yml

fr:
  routes:
    test: "teste"
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a routes.yml file with routes: as main key and the routes you want to translate one level deeper

```
# config/locales/routes.yml
routes:
  activities: "something_else"
```

and call it like that in routes.rb

```
resources :activities, path: I18n.t('activities', locale: :routes)
```

Then you're independent of the language set in I18n.locale

Output is something like this:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
   activities GET    /something_else(.:format)          activities#index
              POST   /something_else(.:format)          activities#create
 new_activity GET    /something_else/new(.:format)      activities#new
edit_activity GET    /something_else/:id/edit(.:format) activities#edit
     activity GET    /something_else/:id(.:format)      activities#show
              PATCH  /something_else/:id(.:format)      activities#update
              PUT    /something_else/:id(.:format)      activities#update
              DELETE /something_else/:id(.:format)      activities#destroy
```

EDIT: overlooked that you also want to translate new and edit, you can do something like that:

```
scope(path_names: { new: I18n.t('new', locale: :routes), edit: I18n.t('edit', locale: :routes) }) do
  resources :activities, path: I18n.t('activities', locale: :routes)
end
```

Or you can override it hardcoded in routes.rb like mentioned in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths